# What characters are allowed in a Google App Engine Key?

Tags: regex, google-app-engine, key

While testing my Google App Engine application, I search for links which include app engine keys. For example:

```
/story/ag5yZXBsaWUtdGVzdGluZ3IMCxIFU3RvcnkY-w0M/
```

What characters are allowed in these keys? I had been using the regex `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, but it seems "-" is also allowed. What else?

Is there a reference on this? I can't find it in the App engine docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google App Engine keys are encoded using URL safe base 64 encoding (see [The source code for the Key datastore type](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py)).

Comment: I would guess its safe to say that the deployed version uses this too, and that its not just the development server.

Answer (score 1):

it's very probably all digits, upper- and lowercase letters, underscore and hyphen (try to base64.urlsafe_b64decode this string ;) )