# Regular expression for Google app engine entity keys

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

I found this post, and now i want to use that regular expression too
[What characters are allowed in a Google App Engine Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940128/what-characters-are-allowed-in-a-google-app-engine-key)

However, in my handler i write something like

```
('/xxx/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]', MyHandler)
```

but it doesn't work...when i try to access a link it says not found...i tried many variations but can't seem to make it happen...Help?!

EDIT : Thanks for the help guys...such a foolish mistake :)

Comment: Without seeing your code, this could be lots of things, but perhaps you meant `('/xxx/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+', MyHandler)`

Comment: the problem is surely caused by the regular expression...because if i put something like "(\w+)"...everything works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression matches just *one* character after the `/xxx/` part. You need to specify that you want 1 **or more** by adding the `+` multiplier:

```
('/xxx/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+', MyHandler)
```

Now your expression matches anything that has *at least* 1 character, not just 1 and nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

Your handler currently allows only exactly one character. Also, for safety, the dash should always be at the end of a character class, lest it designate a range:

```
('/xxx/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*', MyHandler)
```

Answer (score 1):

Keys can also only be [500](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4813780) bytes long, so I am using the following

```
pattern = re.compile('^[0-9A-Za-z._-]{1,500}$')
valid = bool(pattern.match('key-name-to-test'))
```

Old question, but I thought I would add this for future views.